# Determining the convergance value of a infinite series using the avarege values

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I saw a method for determining a value of governance for an infinite series, by looking at the partial sums and taking the average of consecutive sums. Then it looks like the average itself approaches the value of convergence. For example, take $$\sum_{i=0}^n (\frac {1}{2})^{i} = 1 + \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}...$$
Now, by the convergence formula or by evaluating partial sums we see that the series is clearly convergent to $2$. But I am wondering if the method of taking the average for each partial sum, for example, $\frac {1+3/2}{2}=\frac {5}{4}, \frac {1+3/2 +7/4}{3}=\frac {17}{12}$ (which itself leads to $2$) is valid for any convergent infinite series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're talking about is known as Cesàro convergence. Take any sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and consider the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$. Define the sequence of partial sums:
$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$$

We say that this series is Cesàro summable iff the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k$$

The limit is, then, called the Cesàro sum of the series. Now, there is a theorem that says that if your series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges to some $a$, then  the series is also Cesàro summable to $a$. I can give a proof of this if you want.

In fact, there are a bunch of different types of Cesàro convergence and a whole number of theorems which go along with these types. I've just informed you about one type above.

**Edit:**

Right, so the proof is as follows. We suppose that $s_n \to a$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then:
$$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \geq N: |s_n-a| < \epsilon$$

Next, let $n > N$. Then:
$$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k - a \right| = \frac{1}{n} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} (s_k-a) \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} |s_k-a| + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N}^{n} |s_k-a|$$

I've done a bunch of different things here. If you want clarification on any step, then let me know. Essentially, I've split the sum and then used the triangle inequality towards the end there. Now, we know that for $k \geq N$, $|s_k-a| < \epsilon$. Therefore:
$$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k - a \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} |s_k-a| + \epsilon \left(\frac{n-N+1}{n} \right)$$

That right hand side can, then, be made as small as we want it to be. So, we are done. I'm leaving out a number of formal details (and in some cases, I am just being absolutely lazy) but I hope that this illustrates the point well enough.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to know if the Cesàro sum of series is applicable to all converging infinite series. If you could provide proof, that would be really helpful.

Comment: I've included a brief proof for you, let me know if you have any questions about it because I didn't try to be super detailed or formal.